# Acceder a la informacion de tag contenido dentro de otro tag identificado por una clase

Tags: javascript, html, script, dom

Buen dia estoy pixelando con GTM y requiero sacar el valor del heading de una etiqueta h1 que está dentro de una etiqueta div que tiene una clase.

```
<div class="page-header-headings">>
     <h1>Test 1 Course full name</h1></div>
```

He intentado con este script:

```
function() {
     var courseName = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header-headings");
     return courseName[0];}
```

Pero me retorna el primer codigo que puse (El div seguido de h1)

Ahora si pongo:

```
function() {
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header-headings");
     var y = x.getElementsByTagName("h1");
     return y;}
```

Me retorna undefined

Necesito que lo que me retorne diga "Test 1 Course full name"

Ya logré hacer que me retorne el valor que quiero pero haciendo uso de una variable de un script que se ejecuta en la pagina pero quiero saber como se haría el proceso utilizando los valores contenidos dentro de las etiquetas.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo quieres acceder al texto dentro de H1 puedes usar esto:

El querySelector nos devolverá justo lo que necesitamos.

De la otra forma tendrías que utilizar getElementsByClassName y getElementsByTagName

```js
var courseName = document.querySelector(".page-header-headings > h1").innerHTML;


var courseName2 = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header-headings");


console.log("querySelector -> " + courseName);

console.log("getElementsByClassName + getElementsByTagName -> " + courseName2[0].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="page-header-headings">
  <h1>Test 1 Course full name</h1>
</div>
```